# How can I set a variable to the source of a website in AppleScript without cURL?

Tags: curl, applescript

I need to load a webpage in the browser and assign the source to a variable in AppleScript.

I've used cURL in the past to accomplish this, but this is not acceptable for this particular script.  Please help me accomplish the same without cURL.

Here's a working example with `cURL`:

```
set myIP to (do shell script "curl -sL http://icanhazip.com")
```

How do recommend doing the same without cURL?

Comment: Should it use the default browser? Or Safari? Should the page be made visible? Why is use of `curl` not acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for your answer below. It can be visible, or invisible. And it can use any browser, just not command line. I'm testing the browser is using a proxy correctly. I can force curl to use a proxy just fine, but in this case I need to confirm a browser is using the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on Safari <del>v7.0.3</del> v13 (Catalina).

Loading a URL synchronously - a prerequisite for accessing the `source` property - was surprisingly painful - the comments in `openUrlSync()` tell the woeful tale.
<sup>Tip of the hat to [Les Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4576121/les-brown) for an update to the loop condition.</sup>

```applescript
# Specify URL and loading behavior:
set targetUrl to "http://example.com/"
set asNewWin to false
set activateNew to true

# Load the URL *synchronously* in Safari, using the helper
# function below - without activating Safari itself.
set newTab to my openUrlSync(targetUrl, asNewWin, activateNew)

# Note: To additionally make Safari the frontmost application, use:
# activate application "Safari"

# Now that we know that the page has finished loading,
# we can access its `source` property to obtain the HTML
# source and store it in variable `pageSource`
tell application "Safari" to set pageSource to source of newTab


# ---- HELPER FUNCTION
# SYNOPSIS
#   my openUrlSync(targetUrl, asNewWin, activateNew)
# DESCRIPTION
#   Opens a URL in Safari *synchronously* and returns the new tab.
#   CAVEAT: To be safe, access the properties of the returned tab object in the Safari context.
#     targetUrl ... the URL to open
#     asNewWin ... true: open the URL in a new window; false: open it in a new tab in the front window, at the end
#     activateNew ... true: activate the new window/tab; false: do NOT activate the new window/tab;
#        Note: Safari itself is NEVER activated (doesn't become the frontmost application).
# COMMENTS
#   Loading synchronously allows safe access to the properties of the tab returned, notably the `source`
#   property.
#   Tested on Safari 7.0.3.
#  CAVEATS: 
#    - Safari can get into states where this function HANGS.
#    - Creating a new window without activating it makes the interactive
#      window management behave oddly; e.g., `File > Close All Windows`
#      doesn't include the windows created here.
# EXAMPLE:
#   set newTab to my openUrlSync("http://example.com", true, true)
#   tell application "Safari" to set pageSource to source of newTab
on openUrlSync(targetUrl, asNewWin, activateNew)

    tell application "Safari"

        local newTab

        if asNewWin or not (exists front window) then # Make new window.
            # !! The document returned by `make new document` is NOT directly   usable - 
            # !! it seems to change its identity as the page is being loaded.
            # Note: This DOES make the new window the active one in Safari.
            # !! Trying to keep the window invisible with `{URL:targetUrl, visible: false}` is IGNORED.
            make new document at end of documents with properties {URL:targetUrl}
            # !! The following does not make the window INVISIBLE, but it places it LAST among
            # !! the open windows.
            if not activateNew then set visible of front window to false
            # !! We CAN get a persistent reference to the new tab, but only via `current tab` and `front window`.
            set newTab to current tab of front window
        else # Make new tab in front window (at the end).
            # Note: This does NOT activate the new tab.
            # !! Trying to keep the tab invisible with `{URL:targetUrl, visible: false}` BREAKS the statement.
            # !! Ditto for a separate `set visible of newTab to false` statement.
            tell front window to set newTab to make new tab with properties {URL:targetUrl}
            if activateNew then set current tab of front window to newTab
        end if

        # Wait until the page has finished loading,
        # as indicated by the `source` property having a value, 
        # the HTML source code.
        tell newTab
            # NOTE: This loop condition works as of Safari v13.
            #       In v7, for which the answer was originally written,
            #       the following had to be used:
            #         repeat while not (exists URL)
            repeat while source = ""
                delay 0.5
            end repeat
        end tell

        return newTab

    end tell

end openUrlSync
```

Comment: OpenUrlSync is worth this entire answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it; the "quirkiness" of even Apple's own applications' AppleScript support (or lack thereof) never ceases to disappoint me.

Comment: Thanks, @LesBrown; indeed that seems to necessary in recent versions of Safari - I've updated the answer accordingly.